# Capturing Nightwatch assertions and updating in browserstack as failure reason

Tags: nightwatch.js, browserstack

How can we capture assertion failure message in nightwatch test case and pass it to aftermethod method so that it can be passed to Failure reason in Browserstack.

Below is my code where in i need to capture assertions and pass it to after method -

```
afterEach: function (browser, done) {
      if (browser.currentTest.results.failed) {
        browser.session(function (session) {
          browser.browserStackSessionId = session.sessionId
        }
      );
   request({
      uri: "https://" + user + ":" + key + 
      "@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/" + browser.browserStackSessionId 
      + ".json", 

      method:"PUT", 
      form:{"status":"failed","reason":"Assertion failure"}
      })
   } else {
        done()
      }
  },

  'Google\'s Search Functionality_Fail' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.google.com/ncr')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .verify.title('BrowserStack@')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'BrowserStack\n')
      .pause(1000)
       .end(); 
  }
```

Comment: I believe there are no callbacks on assert. Instead of assert you can use verify. For example: WaitForElementXXX commands takes a parameter **abortOnFailure**, a callback returns information if command fails or passes

Comment: Can we catch the assertions in test and pass err it to afterEach? if yes, can you pls send sample code.

Comment: Not sure if there is an out-of-the-box solution for what you are trying to achieve. But here is something I can suggest: Since you are already capturing session ID, create a global dictionary and add err and associated session ID to it eg: dict[key(obj1)] = obj1;
dict[key(obj2)] = obj2;. Fetch the error message for associated session ID and do the api call

Comment: @BountyHunter.. Thanks for you input, but the thing is that i am getting assertion error but unable to capture it in nightwatch. If you could suggest me how to capture assertion in nightwatch it would be great.